# Assigning values to variable through pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code in c++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int z;
  int v1,v2;
  int *p1,*p2;

  p1 = &v1;
  p2= &v2;

  *p1 = 15; // value pointed by p1 is 10
  *p2 = *p1; // value pointed ny p2 is the value pointed by p1 which at the moment is 10.
  p1 =p2; //p1 is assigned the value of p2 which is 10
   *p1 = 20; // the value pointed by p1 is 20;

   cout<<"v1:"<<v1<<endl;
   cout<<"v2:"<<v2<<endl;

   cin>>z;
}
```

Here the output is `v1:15`, `v2:20`. 
I am little confused here, p1 points to address of v1,the latest value pointed by p1 is 20 not 15, so how come the output shows `v1:15`

With the output i assume that the value assigned immediately to the pointer after the pointer is pointing to the address of a variable counts rather than the latest value.Is that correct?

Comment: The value of `p2` is `&v2`, not 10. Pointers hold addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reassigning p1 to point to the same location as p2, which happens to point to v2. This means that when you are setting the value pointed to by p1 to 20, you are writing to v2 and not to v1.